# using vba in excel copy row 1 only if row 2 is populated

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy the contents in A1:AV1 only if B2:BV2 is populated.  I want to copy blank without ending up pasting tab or spaces in blank cells.  As a step two I need to copy B2:BV2 to row C eliminating any blank cell.  Step three I need to take those entries from row C so that only 4 entries populate the following rows D through the end (no more than 10 rows).
I came up with the following with only a partial paste (the best I could do).

```
Sub Copy()

    If IsEmpty(Range("A2").Value) = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Copy Range("A3")
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("B2").Value) = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Copy Range("B3")
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("C2").Value) = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Copy Range("C3")
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("D2").Value) = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Copy Range("D3")
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("E2").Value) = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Copy Range("E3")
    End If
    Sheet1.Range("a3:Y3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A4")

End Sub
```

This worked until AO after that it broke down and did not copy the correct cells.  I know this should be done is come type of an array, but I couldn't figure out the loop.

Answer (score 1):

First make better a loop for cell check and copy like this that will include all conditions you want:
PS. i mean the logic in the code not just a code i wrote:

```
    For I = 1 To Sheet1.Columns.Count
        If Sheet1.Cells(1, I).Value <> "" and not IsNull(Sheet1.Cells(1, I).Value) Then
            I2=I2+1
            Sheet1.Cells(2, I2).Value=Sheet1.Cells(1, I).Value
        End if

        If Sheet1.Cells(2, I2).Value <> "" and not IsNull(Sheet1.Cells(2, I2).Value) Then
            I3=I3+1
            Sheet1.Cells(3, I3).Value=Sheet1.Cells(1, I2-1).Value
        End if
```

after this point i think you can move forward. otherwise write what you face.